# How can I use django-admin.py?

Tags: python

I am a beginner to coding and decided to start with Python. I am following 'Intro To Django with Python For Web Development' by coderschool on youtube as my first project. When I enter `django-admin.py startproject mysite` into the PowerShell prompt, I get a 'modify setup' pop-up from the Python programme.

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried everything I can think of, including Modifying, repairing, uninstall and re-installing but I still keep getting the same pop up. How can I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `django-admin startproject mysite` instead of admin.py.

Django docs -

> If you installed Django using a Linux distribution's package manager (e.g. apt-get or yum) django-admin.py may have been renamed to django-admin. You may continue through this documentation by omitting .py from each command.

I am running Windows 10 and admin.py won't work for me, so I don't think its limited to Linux distros.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Been stuck for hours deleting random stuff and that's all I had to do lol

Comment: @S.Gutridge Glad it helped!